# Instance and Instance's AMI's Kernel-ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

When you create an AMI Image of an EC2 Instance the kernel-id of an instance and AMI's kernel-id will always be the same, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It defaults to the kernel-id of the original instance. However, you can always change it at create time, assuming it's a compatible kernel.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `create-image` through the API / command line / web console, then yes, the AKI (kernel image) associated with the new AMI will be the same as the AKI of the running instance.

If you want to use a different AKI you could:

- stop the instance
- snapshot the root EBS volume
- register the snapshot as a new AMI, specifying a different AKI id.
- start the instance

This is the procedure followed by `create-image` but it defaults to using the same AKI.

That said, it would be a rare situation where you wanted to use a different AKI as the default on Amazon is to us PV-GRUB, which just loads the kernel from the image on your AMI.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration,It is pain in the (...) to find an AMI from an instance id. I want to get an AMI which was created from any given instance id. However I will as this as a separate question.